# Removing wireframe lines in html canvas

Tags: canvas, three.js, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I am facing problem to remove wireframe lines in below link.if you go to that link,you can see wireframe lines by unclicking check button and there is some triangle white lines which i want to remove or hide.
Can some one help me.

Here is the [**link**](http://jsfiddle.net/rjw57/CJy24/)

```js
var maximumTriangleCount = 200;
var maxAllowableBadness = 1e-2;

// The control points which represent the top-left, top-right and bottom
// right of the image.
var controlPoints = [{
    x: 100,
    y: 100
  },
  {
    x: 300,
    y: 100
  },
  {
    x: 300,
    y: 400
  },
  {
    x: 100,
    y: 400
  }
];

var backgroundImgElement = document.getElementById('background');
var imgElement = document.getElementById('screen');
var canvasElement = document.getElementById('canvasElement');
var svgElement = document.getElementById('svgElement');
var drawSkeletonElement = document.getElementById('drawSkeleton');
var containerElement = document.getElementById('container')

initialize();

function initialize() {
  drawSkeletonElement.onchange = redrawImg;
  imgElement.onload = redrawImg;
  backgroundImgElement.onload = resizeElements;

  resizeElements();
  setupDragging();
  redrawImg();
}

function resizeElements() {
  var w = backgroundImgElement.naturalWidth;
  var h = backgroundImgElement.naturalHeight;
  containerElement.style.width = w + 'px';
  containerElement.style.height = h + 'px';
  svgElement.style.width = w + 'px';
  svgElement.style.height = h + 'px';
  canvasElement.width = w;
  canvasElement.height = h;
  redrawImg();
}

function redrawImg() {
  var drawSkeleton = !!(drawSkeletonElement.checked);

  var w = imgElement.naturalWidth,
    h = imgElement.naturalHeight;

  var srcPoints = [{
      x: 0,
      y: 0
    }, // top-left
    {
      x: w,
      y: 0
    }, // top-right
    {
      x: w,
      y: h
    }, // bottom-right
    {
      x: 0,
      y: h
    } // bottom-left
  ];

  var ctx = canvasElement.getContext('2d');
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvasElement.width, canvasElement.height);

  var projPoints = findQuadProjectiveDepths(controlPoints);

  var triangles = [{
      src: [srcPoints[0], srcPoints[1], srcPoints[2]],
      dst: [projPoints[0], projPoints[1], projPoints[2]]
    },
    {
      src: [srcPoints[2], srcPoints[3], srcPoints[0]],
      dst: [projPoints[2], projPoints[3], projPoints[0]]
    }
  ];

  // Keep sub-dividing until we're done
  var triIdx = 0;
  while ((triIdx < triangles.length) && (triangles.length < maximumTriangleCount)) {
    var newTris = subdivideTriangle(triangles[triIdx]);
    if (newTris.length == 1) {
      // no subdivision performed
      triIdx++;
    } else {
      // remove original triangle and add new ones
      triangles.splice(triIdx, 1);
      triangles = triangles.concat(newTris);
    }
  }

  // Draw affine-transformed triangles
  for (var i = 0; i < triangles.length; i++) {
    var src = triangles[i].src;
    var dstProj = triangles[i].dst;

    var dst = [];
    for (var j = 0; j < dstProj.length; j++) {
      var p = dstProj[j];
      dst.push({
        x: p.x / p.z,
        y: p.y / p.z
      });
    }

    var T = affineTransformationFromTriangleCorners(src, dst);

    ctx.save();

    // set clip
    trianglePath(ctx, dst);
    ctx.clip();

    // draw image
    ctx.transform(T[0], T[1], T[2], T[3], T[4], T[5]);
    ctx.drawImage(imgElement, 0, 0);

    ctx.restore();

    if (drawSkeleton) {
      trianglePath(ctx, dst);
      ctx.lineWidth = 2;
      ctx.strokeStyle = '#080';
      ctx.stroke();
    }
  }

  if (drawSkeleton) {
    svgElement.style.visibility = 'visible';
  } else {
    svgElement.style.visibility = 'hidden';
  }
}

function subdivideTriangle(inputTri) {
  // Work out badness of each edge
  var worstEdge = {
    badness: -1,
    corners: null
  };
  for (var cornerIdx = 0; cornerIdx < inputTri.dst.length; cornerIdx++) {
    var corner1Idx = cornerIdx,
      corner2Idx = (cornerIdx + 1) % inputTri.dst.length;
    var dz = inputTri.dst[corner1Idx].z - inputTri.dst[corner2Idx].z;
    var badness = Math.abs(dz);
    if (badness > worstEdge.badness) {
      worstEdge = {
        badness: badness,
        corners: [corner1Idx, corner2Idx]
      };
    }
  }

  // If the maximum badness is OK, don't subdivide
  if (worstEdge.badness < maxAllowableBadness) {
    return [inputTri];
  }

  // Going to turn
  //                       
  // A _____ B      A __D__ B
  //   \   /          \/_\/
  //    \ /     =>   F \ / E
  //     C              C

  var srcA = inputTri.src[0],
    dstA = inputTri.dst[0];
  var srcB = inputTri.src[1],
    dstB = inputTri.dst[1];
  var srcC = inputTri.src[2],
    dstC = inputTri.dst[2];

  var srcD = {
    x: (srcA.x + srcB.x) / 2,
    y: (srcA.y + srcB.y) / 2
  };
  var dstD = {
    x: (dstA.x + dstB.x) / 2,
    y: (dstA.y + dstB.y) / 2,
    z: (dstA.z + dstB.z) / 2
  };
  var srcE = {
    x: (srcB.x + srcC.x) / 2,
    y: (srcB.y + srcC.y) / 2
  };
  var dstE = {
    x: (dstB.x + dstC.x) / 2,
    y: (dstB.y + dstC.y) / 2,
    z: (dstB.z + dstC.z) / 2
  };
  var srcF = {
    x: (srcC.x + srcA.x) / 2,
    y: (srcC.y + srcA.y) / 2
  };
  var dstF = {
    x: (dstC.x + dstA.x) / 2,
    y: (dstC.y + dstA.y) / 2,
    z: (dstC.z + dstA.z) / 2
  };

  return [{
      src: [srcA, srcD, srcF],
      dst: [dstA, dstD, dstF]
    },
    {
      src: [srcD, srcB, srcE],
      dst: [dstD, dstB, dstE]
    },
    {
      src: [srcC, srcF, srcE],
      dst: [dstC, dstF, dstE]
    },
    {
      src: [srcD, srcE, srcF],
      dst: [dstD, dstE, dstF]
    },
  ]
}

function findQuadProjectiveDepths(corners) {
  // See http://www.reedbeta.com/blog/2012/05/26/quadrilateral-interpolation-part-1/

  // Firstly, find the centre point:
  var centre = intersectLines(
    [corners[0], corners[2]], [corners[1], corners[3]]);

  // Lengths of diagonals
  var d02 = dist(corners[0], corners[2]);
  var d13 = dist(corners[1], corners[3]);

  // Find a projective homogeneous representation for each corner point
  // with the correct projective co-ordinate. See the site referenced in
  // the top comment for some more details.

  var tl_z = d02 / dist(corners[0], centre);
  var tl_hom = {
    x: tl_z * corners[0].x,
    y: tl_z * corners[0].y,
    z: tl_z
  };

  var tr_z = d13 / dist(corners[1], centre);
  var tr_hom = {
    x: tr_z * corners[1].x,
    y: tr_z * corners[1].y,
    z: tr_z
  };

  var br_z = d02 / dist(corners[2], centre);
  var br_hom = {
    x: br_z * corners[2].x,
    y: br_z * corners[2].y,
    z: br_z
  };

  var bl_z = d13 / dist(corners[3], centre);
  var bl_hom = {
    x: bl_z * corners[3].x,
    y: bl_z * corners[3].y,
    z: bl_z
  };

  return [tl_hom, tr_hom, br_hom, bl_hom];
}

function trianglePath(ctx, points) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(points[0].x, points[0].y);
  ctx.lineTo(points[1].x, points[1].y);
  ctx.lineTo(points[2].x, points[2].y);
  ctx.closePath();
}

function setupDragging() {
  // Use d3.js to provide user-draggable control points
  var rectDragBehav = d3.behavior.drag().on('drag', rectDragDrag);

  var dragT = d3.select(svgElement).selectAll('circle')
    .data(controlPoints)
    .enter().append('circle')
    .attr('cx', function(d) {
      return d.x;
    })
    .attr('cy', function(d) {
      return d.y;
    })
    .attr('r', 20)
    .attr('class', 'control-point')
    .call(rectDragBehav);

  function rectDragDrag(d, i) {
    d.x += d3.event.dx;
    d.y += d3.event.dy;
    d3.select(this).attr('cx', d.x).attr('cy', d.y);
    redrawImg();
  }
}

function affineTransformationFromTriangleCorners(before, after) {
  /*
   Return the a, b, c, d, e, f parameters needed by the transform() 
   canvas function which will transform the three points in *before* to the
   corresponding ones in *after*. The points should be specified as
   [{x:x1,y:y1}, {x:x2,y:y2}, {x:x3,y:y2}].
  */

  /*
   Calling the before points [x1, y1], etc and the after points [x1',
   y1'], etc, then the affine transformation matrix must do this:

      [ x1' x2' x3' ]   [ a c e ] [ x1 x2 x3 ]
      [ y1' y2' y3' ] = [ b d f ] [ y1 y2 y3 ]
      [ 1   1   1   ]   [ 0 0 1 ] [ 1  1  1  ]

      `-------------'   `-------' `----------'
             Y        =     T          X

   We know matrices Y and X because we're passed them. We want T. So,
   
       T = Y * inverse(X).
  */

  var X, Y, T;

  // Make X matrix
  X = [
    [before[0].x, before[1].x, before[2].x],
    [before[0].y, before[1].y, before[2].y],
    [1, 1, 1]
  ];

  // Make Y matrix
  Y = [
    [after[0].x, after[1].x, after[2].x],
    [after[0].y, after[1].y, after[2].y],
    [1, 1, 1]
  ];

  // Compute T matrix using Numeric. If you wanted, you could work out the
  // inverse of X long-hand but life is too short.
  T = numeric.dot(Y, numeric.inv(X));

  // We only want specific elements from T
  return [T[0][0], T[1][0], T[0][1], T[1][1], T[0][2], T[1][2]];
}

function intersectLines(line1, line2) {
  /*
      Return an object of the form {x: ..., y: ...} which specifies the
      intersection of the two lines specified as an array of two points.
  */

  // See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line-line_intersection

  var x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3, x4, y4;

  x1 = line1[0].x;
  y1 = line1[0].y;
  x2 = line1[1].x;
  y2 = line1[1].y;
  x3 = line2[0].x;
  y3 = line2[0].y;
  x4 = line2[1].x;
  y4 = line2[1].y;

  var denominator = (x1 - x2) * (y3 - y4) - (y1 - y2) * (x3 - x4);

  return {
    x: ((x1 * y2 - y1 * x2) * (x3 - x4) - (x1 - x2) * (x3 * y4 - y3 * x4)) / denominator,
    y: ((x1 * y2 - y1 * x2) * (y3 - y4) - (y1 - y2) * (x3 * y4 - y3 * x4)) / denominator
  };
}

// Utility function to compute distance between points
function dist(a, b) {
  var dx = a.x - b.x;
  var dy = a.y - b.y;
  return Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
}
```

```css
#container {
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}

#container * {
  position: absolute;
}

#screen {
  visibility: hidden;
}

circle.control-point {
  fill: red;
  fill-opacity: 0.25;
}

circle.control-point:hover {
  stroke: yellow;
  stroke-width: 2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.numericjs.com/lib/numeric-1.2.6.min.js"></script>

<p>
  Drag points around to distort image.
  <input type="checkbox" checked="1" id="drawSkeleton">
  <label for="drawSkeleton">Draw wireframe and control points.</label>
</p>
<div id="container">
  <img id="background" src="http://i.imgur.com/MsiT8ha.jpg">
  <img id="screen" src="http://i.imgur.com/Y5YHG8v.jpg">
  <canvas id="canvasElement"></canvas>
  <svg id="svgElement"></svg>
</div>
```

[here is the snap of the issue you can see the dotted lines appears on the perspective while draging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uoajK.png)

Comment: The three.js `CanvasRenderer` handles that with the `material.overdraw` property. `overdraw = 0.5` tends to work well. See https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/examples/js/renderers/CanvasRenderer.js and search for "Hide anti-alias gaps".

Comment: ok thanks for your valuable reply.May i know,in native canvas cant we hide or remove the lines i.e canvas.context.moveTo() and canvas.context.lineTo() drawn lines from the above link example

Comment: I do not think what you are referring to are 'lines'. That is the background showing through. Set the background to red to verify.

Comment: Code added properly

Comment: @WestLangley i have updated question,you can see the snapshot that contains cross lines that i want to remove.At the bottom of the question i added snapshot link.

Comment: Like I said, they are not 'lines'. What you are seeing are gaps between the triangles you are rendering. See my first comment.